# Java - AAC MP4 - How to get media length?

Tags: java, mp4, aac

Does anybody know how to get media length of the aac ( audio format ) mp4 ( file format ) audio in Java?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution I found ( using [mp4parser on github](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) ):

```
public static long getAudioLength(byte[] content) throws Exception {
    IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile(new MemoryDataSourceImpl(content));
    double lengthInSeconds = (double)isoFile.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().getDuration() / isoFile.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().getTimescale();
    return (long)lengthInSeconds;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

muxer (mentioned by @user3489820) was hived from mp4parser and now lives separately at: [org.mp4parser/muxer](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mp4parser/muxer). The Maven package was changed to `org.mp4parser/mp4parser`. For more information see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mp4parser/isoparser and see the [IsoParser](https://jar-download.com/javaDoc/org.mp4parser/isoparser/1.9.39/index.html), [muxer](https://jar-download.com/javaDoc/org.mp4parser/muxer/1.9.39/index.html) and [streaming](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.mp4parser/streaming/1.9.39/documentation) JavaDoc.

I updated @user3489820's code example, added imports, factored out redundant code and eliminated unnecessary casts. I also removed the `MemoryDataSourceImpl` call because my project needed to discover the length of an MP4 file on disk, and that class was not needed:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.mp4parser.IsoFile;
import org.mp4parser.boxes.iso14496.part12.MovieHeaderBox;

public class Blah {
    public static long getAudioLength(File file) throws Exception {
        IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile(file);
        MovieHeaderBox mhb = isoFile.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox();
        return mhb.getDuration() / mhb.getTimescale();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code...

File file = new File("filename.mp3");
AudioFileFormat baseFileFormat = new MpegAudioFileReader().getAudioFileFormat(file);
Map properties = baseFileFormat.properties();
Long duration = (Long) properties.get("duration");

Comment: It's MP3, not AAC.
MpegAudioFileReader is designed for MP3

Comment: For the moment, I am stuck with JAAD.
The problem is, that mp4 file I am trying to parse has sample tables in the end. This means, that I need RandomAccessFile to parse it, but I only has ByteArrayInputStream.
So...
One solution is to recreate a file on a file system ( and that's bad for the server )...although, I don't like this solution

Comment: Tried, hasn't found how to work with "in-memory" aac files ( ie from ByteArrayInputStream or just byte[] )

Comment: Finally, found the solution with mp4 parser ( it's not from google, it's just on google code ).

Comment: Ok, found it. Should have devoted more time to try with mp4 parser

Answer (score -1):

You can use ffmpeg to get the duration of any media:

First get the output of the command from the runtime:

```
  public String execute(String cmd) {
    String output=null;
      try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr=rt.exec(cmd);
        final InputStream es=pr.getErrorStream();
        class C extends Thread {
          String type, output="";
          InputStream is;
          public C(InputStream is, String type) { this.is=is; this.type=type; }
          public void run() {
            try {
              InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
              String line=null;
              while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
                output+=line+" ";
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }
          }
        };
        C t=new C(es);
        t.start();
        int exitVal=pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
        output=""+t.output;
      }
      catch(Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }
      return output;
  }
```

Then parse the output for "Duration":

```
  public int getTime(String out) {
    int i=0, j=0, k, l, x=0, y=0, ind=0;
    String d="", frs="";
    BufferedReader dis=null;
    String nextline=out;
    ind=0;
    if((ind=nextline.indexOf("Duration:"))>-1)
      d=nextline.substring(ind+9, nextline.indexOf(',', ind+1)).trim();
      int ind2=0;
      int h=0, m=0, s=0, xxx=0;
      if((ind=d.indexOf(":"))>-1) {
        h=Integer.parseInt(d.substring(ind2, ind));
        ind2=ind+1;
      }
      if((ind=d.indexOf(":", ind+1))>-1) {
        m=Integer.parseInt(d.substring(ind2, ind));
        ind2=ind+1;
      }
      if((ind=d.indexOf(".", ind+1))>-1) {
        s=Integer.parseInt(d.substring(ind2, ind));
      }
      if(ind<d.length()) {
        ind2=ind+1;
        if((ind=d.indexOf(".", ind+1))>-1) {
          xxx=Integer.parseInt(d.substring(ind2, d.length()));
        }
      }
      try {
        dis.close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex) { }
    return h*3600+m*60+s;
  }
```

In total:

```
  String out=execute("ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4");
  int time=getTime(out);
```